# Strange UIButton behaviour on iOS5

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton

I create a `UIButton` and place it on top of the `UIImageView` which I place on `UIScrollView`. I add the button to the image like this:

```
backgroundImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backgroundImage.frame.size.width, mainTextView.frame.origin.y + mainTextView.frame.size.height + bottomMargin + attachBlockHeight);
        [self insertSubview:backgroundImage atIndex:0];

        UIButton *tmpButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, imgGreyLine.frame.origin.y + imgGreyLine.frame.size.height, backgroundImage.frame.size.width, attachBlockHeight)]; 
        [tmpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAttachClicked) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
        //tmpButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [backgroundImage addSubview:tmpButton];
```

And the button works great on `iOS6` and up - it's there, it receives touch events and does what it has to do.

However, on `iOS5` I encounter an enormously strange behaviour - the `frame` of the button stays exactly the same and the button is clearly present on the `view`, but it *only* receives touch events when I **slide** my finger left or right on it. Moreover, there are no other `UIViews` on top of the button anywhere near!

What can be the reason for it? I'm totally confused in finding the bug here.

**EDIT**: It turns out that sliding `UIButton` works on `iOS6` as well, but the thing is that the touch events are also registered.

Comment: Any gesture recognizers involved in this scenario?

Comment: @Stavash nope, none of 'em

Comment: What's going on in the view hierarchy? I see you're inserting the UIImageView under all other views

Comment: I think the problem is AutoResizeSubview check box. plz uncheck all autoresizesubview check box.

Comment: @Stavash I add a custom UIView to UIScrollView. This view contains the image at index:0, a label and a UIButton. That's how it works

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD there is no checkbox to check when you are not using Storyboards and write everything in code as I do, Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable user interaction on the UIImageView parent

eg:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[backgroundImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[backgroundImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];

UIButton *tmpButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,50,50)];
[tmpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAttachClicked) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
tmpButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[backgroundImage addSubview:tmpButton];
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, I still don't see how it works in one system and changes behaviour in another. No way some userInteraction BOOL can be in place here.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add UIbutton as a subview of UIImageview. Add it to the scrollview or the superview of UIimageview for that matter

Comment: Why can't I, for Christ's sake? Even when I add it to the superview of the UIImageView nothing changes, as expected.

Comment: Can you post the target method of your button @SergiusGee

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference, but here you go -  `-(void)btnAttachClicked{
    NSLog(@"CLICKED!!!");
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way to do what you want is to have a UIView with the imageview and button as siblings/children. make sure to disable user interaction on the imageview and you should be good.

Comment: I did disable the user interaction and even after adding the UIButton to the superview of UIImageView - the UIView that hosts all this and which is the added to the UIScrollView - nothing worked!